# How to transform a graph on the xaxis to look like example image?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot the error rate for knn models against 1/k like the following example:
[image: Example Image to replicate]

I have the data (error rates and values for 1/k), however, most of the values for 1/k are very close together and difficult to interpret. I have tried setting the tick intervals like below, but I need the ticks to be evenly spaced like in the example. I've spent the better part of two hours looking for a solution but to no avail. Does anyone know the R function that would allow me to do this?

My results

[image: My results]

My results with tick intervals

[image: My results with tick intervals]

**table with results**
[results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Eoa.png)

If needed, here is the Rcode for the plot:

**tick intervals**

```
k_ticks <- c(0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.10, 0.20, 0.50, 1.0)
```

**plot of error rates against 1/k**

```
err_plt <- ggplot(knn_table, aes(x = knn_table$`1.div.k`),
                  position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(aes(y = knn_table$crv.cl.error.rate),
            colour = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = knn_table$cl.error.rate),
            colour = "blue") +  
  xlab("1/K") +
  ylab("Error Rate") + 
  geom_point(aes(y = knn_table$crv.cl.error.rate),
             col = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(y = knn_table$cl.error.rate),
             col = "blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1),breaks = k_ticks)
```

Comment: `knn_table` is not defined here anywhere. Can you paste that one?

Comment: Have you tried `scale_x_sqrt()` instead of the continuous one?

Comment: @teunbrand it definitely spreads the points out a little more, but doesn't set the distances between axis ticks to be the same like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The scale on the `x`-axis in the OP's desired image seems to be log10, so if you can accept slightly-less-than-equal intervals between breaks, using `scale_x_continuous` with `trans = 'log10'` should work.

For example, without scaling:

```
x_vec <- c(0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1)
test_tbl <- tibble::tibble(x = x_vec,
                           y = runif(length(x_vec)))
p <- ggplot(test_tbl, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
p
```

[image]

But now with the x-axis scaled by log10:

```
p + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10', 
                     breaks = x_vec)
```

[image]